# Drop rows of tuple containing specific value

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a data table with containing tuples of words. I wanted to remove/drop rows that contains the word "tolak" and put it in a new dataset. I wanted to also use the code to later drop the rows that contains no more tuple ("[]"). Here's what my data looks like:

```
                  stemming
0  [go, tolak, experience]
1                  [tolak]
2             [nice, look]
3     [love, colour, tabs]
```

Here's what I tried so far, but does not make any changes.

```
df_new = df[df['stemming'] != ('tolak')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check with

```
s = df['stemming'].explode().isin(['tolak'])
df = df.drop(s.index[s])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! This works for removing the rows by the word related rule. Now I'm trying to delete rows that contains no tuple word. Here's the output of `print (df['stemming'].head(3).tolist())`  =  `[['moga', 'cepat', 'cair', 'moga', 'beneran', 'bantu', 'butuh', 'banget'], ['baik', 'sistem', 'selesai'], []]`. I would like to delete the last row as it contains "[]".

Answer (score 0):

Just `map` with a lambda func to test for occurence of word: `tolak`

```
df[df['stemming'].map(lambda x: x and 'tolak' in x)]
```

---

```
                  stemming
0  [go, tolak, experience]
1                  [tolak]
```